# regular expression over multiple lines python

Tags: python, regex

I have a String Alltext that contains text across multiple lines

```
aaaaa    
D0  
aaaaa

text0...........


aaaaa                                      
D1  
aaaaa  
text 1 ..........


aaaaa  
D2  
aaaaa  
text 2
```

I want to keep just the text part i.e. text0...., text1 ,  text2.... and remove the indicators

```
aaaaa
D0
aaaaa, 

aaaaa
D1
aaaaa
```

and so on.These indicate next text segment. I tried this regular expression

```
re.sub("[a]* \sD[0-9]*\\s[a] * ", " ",Alltext)
```

but this just removes D0, D1 and not the aaaa
The output I get

```
aaaaa  
aaaaa   
text0  
aaaaa       
aaaaa  
text1
```

How can I remove these aaaaa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to put a single character inside character class and also you don't need to double escape `\s`

```
a*\s*D[0-9]*\s*a*\s*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/oE0iR5/4)

Python code would be,

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """aaaaa    
D0  
aaaaa

text0...........


aaaaa                                      
D1  
aaaaa  
text 1 ..........


aaaaa  
D2  
aaaaa  
text 2  """
>>> m = re.sub(r'a*\s*D[0-9]*\s*a*\s*', r'', s)
>>> m
'text0...........\n\n\ntext 1 ..........\n\n\ntext 2  '
>>> print m
text0...........


text 1 ..........


text 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 print re.findall(r"^text.*$",x,re.M)
```

Simle findall should do this as well.